# UpdatePanel always post back whole page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel, master-pages, scriptmanager

There is an `UpdatePanel` add inside `UserControl`, and this user control is added inside the `MasterPage`. When clicking on a button in that `UpdatePanl`. The whole page is refreshed. why?

**Master Page:**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="webasite.SiteMaster" %>

<%@ Register Src="views/uc/_aside.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="_aside" %>
<%@ Register Src="views/uc/_page-loader.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="_pageloader" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ar"  direction="rtl" dir="rtl" style="direction: rtl">
    <!--begin::Head-->
    <head>
        <base href="">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
 
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
            
            <uc1:_pageloader runat="server" id="_pageloader" />
            <uc1:_aside runat="server" id="_aside" />           
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**User control: _aside.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="_aside.ascx.cs" Inherits="cidyai.partials.uc._aside" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/app/views/uc/dashboard.ascx" TagPrefix="uc2" TagName="dashboard" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/app/views/uc/drivers.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="drivers" %>
<uc2:dashboard runat="server" ID="dashboard" UpdateMode="Conditional"/>
<uc1:drivers runat="server" id="drivers" UpdateMode="Conditional"/>
```

**User control: drivers.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="drivers.ascx.cs" Inherits="cidyai.app.views.uc.drivers" %>

    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate></ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    
    <form class="form">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-solid" placeholder="Name"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="btn btn-primary mr-2" runat="server" Text="save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </form>
```

Comment: You've got some extra stuff here that probably isn't applicable. We don't need to see the label, the textbox, UpdateProgress, dashboard control declaration, an extra button or anything else that isn't absolutely necessary to demonstrate the issue. Please review [mcve]. You *should* however include the implementation of your server side event handler if in your testing it turns out to be crucial to your example. You've also got an extra "t" attribute in your save button declaration. What that intentional?

Comment: You still have not followed the advice in my comment. Please reread it.